# REGEXEXTRACT formula to extact a strating without using the SPLIT

Tags: regex, google-sheets-formula

I have a text where I need to extract the community name
The delimiter for spliting is " - "

Hence `Iowa - Cedar Rapids - Meth-Wick Community`
must give result as `Meth-Wick Community`

if input is `Iowa - Cedar Rapids - The Gardens of Cedar Rapids`
result must be `The Gardens of Cedar Rapids`

I have tried with

```
=REGEXEXTRACT("Iowa - Cedar Rapids - The Gardens of Cedar Rapids","([\w\s]+)\s-\s([\w\s]+)\s-\s([\w\s]+)")
```

I need to gext the third array value without using the INDEX or SPLIT function

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, ".*\s-\s(.+)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m6y9oT/1/). *Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\s-\s` - whitespace + `-` + whitespace
- `(.+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

See the Google sheets screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant to extract the third element, even in case with other sample data, maybe something like:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"^(?:.*? - ){2}(.*?)(?: - |$)"),""))
```

Where pattern `^(?:.*? - ){2}(.*?)(?: - |$)` matches:

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?:.*? - ){2}` - Any character other than newline upto (lazy) a space-hyphen-space combination (thice!).
- `(.*?)` - A capture group to match any character other than newline in a lazy match upto;
- `(?: - |$)` - A non-capture group to match either a space-hyphen-space combination or the end-string anchor.

---

Sidenote; Not sure why you don't want to use `SPLIT()` nor `INDEX()` but if you want to avoid a much slower regular expression it would still work when you use a nested `SUBSTITUTE()`:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A," - ","|"),"|"),,3)
```